# jQuery code simplification, i'm sure this can be turned into a simple function

Tags: jquery

I can't get my head around how to simplify the following code. It's seems redundant to duplicate code in this way. Its used on http://boboco.techef.net/express.php

```
$('#squareDrop').change(function(){
    var squarePriceCurrent = $('#squarePrice').text();
    var squarePrice = $('#squareDrop option:selected').attr('title');

    $('#squarePrice').increment(squarePriceCurrent, squarePrice);
    $('#squareTotal').val(squarePrice + '.99');
});

$('#portraitDrop').change(function(){
    var portraitPriceCurrent = $('#portraitPrice').text();
    var portraitPrice = $('#portraitDrop option:selected').attr('title');

    $('#portraitPrice').increment(portraitPriceCurrent, portraitPrice);
    $('#portraitTotal').val(portraitPrice + '.99');
});

$('#landscapeDrop').change(function(){
    var landscapePriceCurrent = $('#landscapePrice').text();
    var landscapePrice = $('#landscapeDrop option:selected').attr('title');

    $('#landscapePrice').increment(landscapePriceCurrent, landscapePrice);
    $('#landscapeTotal').val(landscapePrice + '.99');
});
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving working code.

Comment: and link to jsfiddle.net instead of live site, before posting to the forum mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#squareDrop, #portraitDrop, #landscapeDrop').change(function(){
    var priceId = this.id.replace('Drop', 'Price'), totalId = this.id.replace('Drop', 'Total');

    var priceCurrent = $('#' + priceId).text();
    var price = $('option:selected', this).attr('title');

    $('#' + priceId).increment(priceCurrent, price);
    $('#' + totalId).val(price + '.99');
});
```

Comment: Hey, i've dropped your code in but at the mo it's a no go, check that link to see maybe it's something obvious i'm missing. Apologies for not linking to jsFiddle i will in future

Comment: @user2175692 the `#` was missing in the selector, try now

Comment: Ah! Yeah that was it, brilliant thank you so much for helping me out.